# Changing the arrow icon in material Android Text fields / TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, material-ui, material-design

Is there a way to customize the icon of **TextInputLayout** highlighted in yellow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by setting the **endIconDrawable**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_icon" />
```

And to make the custom drawable flip the field is checked, you should create a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_up" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_down" />
</selector>
```